# Is it possible for Raspberry Pi B+ to be act as a Hard Drive using USB to USB connector?

Tags: raspbian, pi-b+, pi-b

i would like to ask if a Raspberry Pi B+ can act as a Hard Drive using USB to USB connector? All i want is to access the MicroSD card of Raspberry Pi B+ to my computer using USB to USB connector? Thanks for your answer(s).

Comment: No. You can use any of the common networking protocols, `ssh`, `ftp`, `afp` (even `Samba`) over Ethernet or WiFi.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible as the Pi model b+ has a built in USB hub that prevents it from being configured as a slave device

Answer (score 0):

one simple(yet troublesome) way would be to use a card reader and connect it to your computer. Otherwise, you can access the files remotely https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/

Just follow the FTP part and I hope this helps ^^ Cheers